# Git thinks i'm pushing to a different (non-existent) repository?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have one github account and can push to other repositories on that account.

I created a repo called Vigenere but then deleted it.

I created a new repo called Vigenere, CLONED it. Added my files in Intellij and PUSHED.

I get

```
17:32:32.938: [Vigenere-master] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master --set-upstream
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MYGITHUB/Vigenere.git'
To https://github.com/MYGITHUB/Vigenere.git
!   refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [rejected] (fetch first)
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
Done
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So it says try a git pull. So then it tells me it looks like those unrelaTED files are from a different project altogether!

```
17:34:55.281: [Vigenere-master] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false pull --progress --no-stat -v --progress origin master
POST git-upload-pack (275 bytes)
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.        
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0        
warning: no common commits
From https://github.com/MYGITHUB/Vigenere
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Comment: LOL how is this a bad question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you created a repository `Vigenere` on your local machine, and then created a repository with the same name on Github. The Github repository contains a single commit with a readme file. Your local repository does not contain that same commit but has a different initial commit.

The solution would be to remove the Github repository (again) and recreate it without readme file, .gitignore file or license. That will create an empty repository. You can push your commits to that repository.

Answer (score 0):

Did not get the whole question but.
 https://github.com/MYGITHUB/Vigenere.git

and 
https://github.com/authentical/Vigenere

are different repos. I am not sure if you tried to censor or this could be a cause.

Comment: Sorry I updated my question. I was supposed to be censoring my github. LOL